# SQL group by a combined value from two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table

[image: table]

and I need this query result

[image: result]

I basically have to make a "unique" value from the columns Nr and S. Then I need to group by this new unique value.

How do I do this.

Comment: which version of sql server you are using??

Comment: Look up `STRING_AGG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

starting from SQL Server 2017 you could use string_agg

```
select id, concat(nr,'-',s) nr_s, k, s
  , STRING_AGG(z_value, ';') z_value
  , STRING_AGG(x_value, ';') x_value
  , STRING_AGG(y_value, ';') y_value
from my_table  
group by id, concat(nr,'-',s), k, s
```